# Is there a better way to segue back to main menu?

Tags: swift, segue

I need several view controllers to segue back to a main menu.  After adding the terminal segues, by adding a button and creating a show segue, my storyboard looks like a rats nest of confusion. Is there a better way to link the terminal view controller back to a main menu, or is this how it's done?[image]

Comment: You must NOT do it like that, because you will not be seguing "back" - you are making a whole _new_ "main menu", so now you will have two of them. And then if you do it again you will have three of them, and so on. You will just pile up view controllers and run out of memory. Instead, learn about _unwind segues_ and use them.

Comment: @matt *unwind* segues should really only be necessary if you need to push data from the terminus (or where ever you're unwinding from) back to the "main menu".  Otherwise, we can simply dismiss all the presented views.

Comment: I don't need to push any data from the terminus, but if I dismiss all presented views, how do I then present the user with the main menu, without segueing back to the main menu via a UIButton action?

Comment: Using UINavigationViewController method popToViewController:animated: would be a better option to go back to the rootViewController                             https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Answer (score 1):

After reading up, it looks like this is the best solution for my needs, since there is no data to push from the terminal view controller.

```
@IBAction func backToMain(sender: AnyObject) {

self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```